# How to fill a pandas dataframe column using a value from another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Firstly we can import some packages which might be useful

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
```

Say I now have a dataframe which has a date, name and age column.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['10-04-2020', '04-07-2019', '12-05-2015' ], 'name': ['john', 'tim', 'sam'], 'age':[20, 22, 27]})
```

Now say I have another dataframe with some random columns

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
```

**Question:**

How can I take the age value in `df1` filtered on the date (can select this value) and populate a whole new column in `df2` with this value? Ideally this method should generalise for any number of rows in the dataframe.

**Tried**

The following is what I have tried (on a similar example) but for some reason it doesn't seem to work (it just shows nan values in the majority of column entries except for a few which randomly seem to populate).

```
y = datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 12)
df2['new'] = df1[(df1['date'] == y)].age
```

***Expected Output***

Since I have filtered above based on sams age (date corresponds to the row with sams name) I would like the new column to be added to df2 with his age as all the entries (in this case 27 repeated 3 times).

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'new': [27, 27, 27]})
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: Sure just added

Comment: what if there are two `sam` one with age `27` and the other with `25`?

Comment: Ah, sorry I just mentioned sams name to make it easier (seems to have complicated things). Ignore that, think of it as filtering by the date which will always be unique, and then selecting the age based of that. So ideally if I change the date specified it should pick out the age number (from ```df1```) and then populate a new column (in ```df2```) with that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
y = datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 12).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
df2.loc[:, 'new'] = df1.loc[df1['date'] == y, "age"].item()

# Output
   a  b  new
0  1  4   27
1  2  5   27
2  3  6   27
```

Comment: Not sure if that works, seems to throw an error.

Comment: That's because dates in df1 are `strings`, whereas y is a `datetime64` object. Try again with the code in my updated answer.

Comment: Would you happen to know why this works and my original method wouldn't? Like if I changed y to a string and then tried using ```df2['new'] = df1[(df1['date'] == y)].age``` is there something wrong with this?

Comment: Your `date` column is not of `datetime` type, rather it is just `string` type. So when you compare `string` to `datetime` object you get an error @nishcs. But this answer does just a `string` to `string` comparison and hence it works.

Comment: but say I turn my datetime into a string using ```y = datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 12).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')``` then is my command ```df2['new'] = df1[(df1['date'] == y)].age``` still a valid solution?

Comment: @nishcs Yes, precisely, because values of df1['date'] are also strings. That's why you need to convert your datetime, in order for the comparison (==) to work.

Answer (score 1):

You'd like to change format of y to Str and try df.loc method

```
y = datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 12)

y=y.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
df2['new']=int(df1.loc[df1['date']==y,'age'].values)
df2
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert df1 `date` column to `datetime` type

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.date, format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Filter dataframe and get the age

```
req_date = '2015-05-12'
age_for_date = df1.query('date == @req_date').age.iloc[0]
```

NOTE: This assumes that there is only one age per date (As explained by OP in comments)

Create a new column

```
df2 = df2.assign(new=age_for_date)
```

Output

```
   a  b  new
0  1  4   27
1  2  5   27
2  3  6   27
```

Comment: Is the assign method better for creating new columns compared to equating?

Comment: Good question @nishcs. I use assign because of its structural simplicity and flexibility in assigning multiple columns using a dictionary. In terms of time efficiency, assign is a tiny bit slower as it does a copy after assigning. For multiple column creation and readability, I prefer it over the simple assignment.